# How to implement a media player using java

Tags: java, media-player

HI!! 
I am in the middle of a project now that incorporates JOGL and I am trying to get a media player working. They File formats that need to be played is not really important but .avi or .mpeg would be desired. I am using netbeans to develop this application.

So far I have tried to do this using JMF but keep getting a error "Unable to handle format: MPEG..."
I have googled this error and done everything possible adding codecs etc. But the image is still not showning up.

I have also tried JavaFX which worked perfectly but trying to get to run from a pure java program very difficult.

Can anyone tell me the best way to implement this. Tutorials etc I really need to get this implemented but keep hitting dead ends any help will be great.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with JVLC to complete this I used the example from [Working JVCL Example](http://sites.google.com/site/xyberabt)

work a charm for me thanks everyone for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest JMF with jffmpeg.  [Link](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I'll try this. I have tried using I think it was fobs I think is the same thing I'll try this though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Windows, dsj DirectShow Java wrapper from [humatic](http://www.humatic.de/htools/dsj.htm) will do the trick too. 
It is not free though, you have to buy a license as soon as you turn commercial.

Comment: thanks going to look at this too Still haven't tried jffmpeg yet I'll check it out though.